# rich:dataTable getting the total from filterBy columns

Tags: jsf, richfaces, richdatatable

I have a rich datatable with columns that I can filter.

```
<!-- Data table with filters -->
<h:form>
<rich:dataTable value="#{sessionScope.paymentsBean.payments}" var="payment"
   id="table">
   <rich:column filterBy="#{sessionScope.payment.invoice}" filterEvent="onkeyup">
      <f:facet name="header">Invoice</f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.payment.invoice}" />
   </rich:column>
   <rich:column filterBy="#{sessionScope.payment.description}" filterEvent="onkeyup">
      <f:facet name="header">Description</f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.payment.description}" />
   </rich:column>
   <rich:column filterBy="#{sessionScope.payment.amount}" filterEvent="onkeyup">
      <f:facet name="header">Amount</f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope.payment.amount}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
</h:form>

<!-- Total -->
<h:outputText id="total" value="#{sessionScope.paymentsBean.total}" >
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" type="currency" currencySymbol="$"/>
</h:outputText>
```

For the total, I can sum all the amounts in sessionScope.paymentsBean.payments to get the total. Which is $355.00 in the following example.

```
Invoice     Description     Amount
1           Cash            $5.00
2           Visa            $50.00
3           Visa            $100.00
4           MasterCard      $200.00 

Total: $355.00
```

However, if I filter by "Visa", the table and total would look like:

```
Invoice     Description     Amount
2           Visa            $50.00
3           Visa            $100.00

Total: $355.00
```

The total should be $150 but getTotal() doesn't know about the filterBy data.
Is there a way to dynamically calculate the total based on the filterBy criteria from the rich:datatable?

Comment: Can you specify RichFaces and JSF versions you are using?

Comment: Sure, I'm using JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3.3 Final.  I can't do any upgrading of these libraries since this is part of a bigger project but it'll be nice to know if JSF 2 or Richfaces 4 has support for it.

Comment: JSF 2 with PrimeFaces you can do it for sure, because Datatable is binded to two list, the main one and the filtered one, so you have the filtered list always available in your backing bean. With PF 1.2 and rich 3.3 I think I did something similar, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to recover the filtered data. You need the table to be binded to a backing bean property and you need it to be a [`rich:extendedDataTable`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/tlddoc/rich/extendedDataTable.html).

`<rich:extendedDataTable value="#{sessionScope.paymentsBean.payments}" var="payment"
   id="table" binding="sessionScope.paymentsBean.table">`

Binded attribute will be [HTMLExtendedDataTable](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.2.GA/en/apidoc/org/richfaces/component/html/HtmlExtendedDataTable.html) type. After that you will need to create an *Ajax* call when user types something in the filter, to be called. See [`<a4j:support />`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html) component and use it when a key is pressed, as:

`<a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="countBox" action="#{sessionScope.paymentsBean.actionCalculateTotalValue}"/>`

Remember calling Ajax method on filterings [can be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279874/1199132). I sincerely suggest to avoid the table's built-in filters and create your custom ones based in `h:inputText` and implement your ajax calls here. You can take a look into this [link](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2008/11/richfaces-filtering-with-custom-function/).

Once the method is called you just need to obtain the filtered rows, calculate the total amount and put in in a variable, over which JSF will update the box when the call is finished. What's the way to get the filtered rows? There you have:

```
public List<E> filteredList() {
    List<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<E>();

    int i = 0;
    boolean loop = true;

    while (loop) {
        table.setRowKey(new Integer(i));
        if (table.isRowAvailable()) {
            list.add((E) table.getRowData());
            i += 1;
        } else {
            loop = false;
        }
    }

    table.setRowKey(null);
    return list;
}
```

Basically it makes a loop until there are no more available rows in the table. Good luck.